# SSH Hangs When Using sshpass and Private Keys

Tags: git, github, ssh, kubernetes, sshpass

I have an *alpine* Docker image running in Kubernetes, in which I try to push to Git using a Deploy Key (with passphrase).

Now my command looks like:

```docker
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=\"sshpass -p mygreatpassphrase ssh -vvv\" git -C /workspace push --mirror git@github.com:foo/bar.git"]
```

The result then is:

```shell
<snip>
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
```

It hangs on this line indefinitely. Sadly it seems there is no more verbose output for `ssh`. I am not sure whether the problem is with `sshpass` inside the container or where the actual problem arises.

Building in Docker hangs, too:

```docker
FROM alpine/git

RUN apk add --no-cache sshpass

RUN sshpass -p foo /bin/sh -c 'read X < /dev/tty'
```

`sshpass` has the following files open:

```shell
lr-x------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 10:43 0 -> pipe:[380942247]
l-wx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 10:43 1 -> pipe:[380942248]
l-wx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 10:43 2 -> pipe:[380944011]
lrwx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 10:43 3 -> /dev/pts/ptmx
lrwx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 10:43 4 -> /dev/pts/0
```

`ssh` in contrast:

```shell
lr-x------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 09:23 0 -> pipe:[380942247]
l-wx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 09:23 1 -> pipe:[380942248]
l-wx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 09:23 2 -> pipe:[380944011]
lrwx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 09:23 3 -> socket:[380944638]
lrwx------    1 tempuser root            64 Jul 31 10:43 4 -> /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 10):

For Keys with a Passphrase, the SSH prompt is different.
So I had to change the prompt using `-P assphrase`:

```docker
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=\"sshpass -p mygreatpassphrase -P assphrase ssh -vvv\" git -C /workspace push --mirror git@github.com:foo/bar.git"]
```

Comment: Thanks! You save me a bunch of time.

Comment: This fixed my issue with `sshpass` hanging, thanks!  To be clear for others reading. you can run `sshpass` as: `sshpass -p "password" -P assphrase ...`.